# Are there any mathematical properties of consecutive integer power modulo operations that could be exploited for algorithmic speed gain?

Tags: performance, modular-arithmetic

I'm attempting to search through all the integers between 10^15 and 10^16 to check if they are in the oeis sequence [A277274](https://oeis.org/A277274), and the entirety of the program can be summarized as mostly equivalent to :

```python
for n in range(int(10**15),int(10**16)):
    if pow(3, n, n) == 11:
        print("Found one: {}".format(n))
```

Since the modulo argument is changing each time through the loop, I can't take advantage of modular arithmetic's property of taking a "running modulo" as n increases, and a speedup of powmod due to the [modulo argument being prime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67677201/3586848) also seems like it wouldn't help too much due to having to prime test the integers, and primes being less dense in my search area (although a Miller-Rabin prime test might help).

Python's builtin powmod implementation seems rather quick to begin with, but simply incrementing through the integers on my modern machine with one thread would take ~250 years to get through them all, whereas someone exhaustively found all the members of A277274 < 10^15 in much less than 25 years. So I assume I'm missing something. (And yes, I do realize the problem is "embarrassingly parallel", but even a 20-fold increase in speed will not help my current algorithm)

I'm positive something is just under my nose. And I'm writing this question half as a brainstorming exercise. But I'm guessing 3 or 11 being prime might help, or the prime factorization of 3^n being trivial might lead somewhere, but no algorithmic speedups spring to mind when reading through the [properties of modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Properties).

Answer (score 1):

Do a sieve.

First you can strike out all multiples of 3, 4, and 11.  You've already gotten rid of over half.

But now the property that you use is that if `p` is a prime then `3^(kp) mod p = 3^k mod p` which has a pattern that repeats with a period of `p-1`.

So, for example, for `5` the pattern goes `3, 2, 1, 4`.  And `11 mod 5` is `1`.  And therefore we strike out 3 out of 4 multiples of `5`.

For `7` the pattern goes `3, 2, 6, 4, 5, 1`.  And `11 mod 7` is `6`.  So we get to strike out 5 out of 6 of the multiples of `7`.

But for `13` the pattern goes, `3, 9, 1, 3, 9, 1, 3, 9, 1, 3, 9, 1`.  So we get to strike out all of the multiples of `13`.  The same is true for `23`.

For `17`, `19` and `29` we get to strike out all but 1.  But for `37` we only get to strike out all but 2.

I think that on average for a prime `p` you will get to strike out `(p-2)/(p-1)` of its multiples.  So continue until you have have struck out most values fairly cheaply.  And then do the remaining ones with your existing test.

There are a number of ways to parallelize. The basic idea being to hand out a bunch of primes to a worker, have it sieve them and divide the sieve into chunks of fixed size.  For each chunk, collect the chunks from all the workers, and use `or` to merge the sieves.  Then walk the sieve and come up with a list of candidates and test them.

This is not embarrassingly parallel.  But it is going to be good enough that I can see how the program could run fast enough to be acceptable.

Comment: I like it, those are nice improvements.  But it sounds like this will still take about $10^{16}$ memory and steps of computation, which I imagine is too much to be feasible?

Comment: I may be missing something obvious, but why is it trivial that multiples of 3 4 and 11 cannot fulfill the congruence  3^n == 11 (mod n) ?

Comment: @brubsby Because 3^n is congruent to 0 mod 3 while 11 isn't.  And 3^n is not congruent to 0 mod 11 while 11 is.  Likewise 3^4k is congruent to 0 or 1 mod 4 while 11 is congruent to 3 mod 4.

Comment: And yes, it takes 10^16 steps, but very fast steps, which is doable if you parallelize.  And you do not need to ever have the full sieve in memory.

Comment: I was a bit confused at the specific line of reasoning you used to arrive at these statements, I guess I haven't internalized the rules of modular arithmetic very well yet. But after proving them explicitly step by step I believe I correctly understand now. However, I'm not sure where exactly `3^(kp) mod p == 3^k mod p` follows from. Part of it is certainly Fermat's Little Theorem, but what theorem/property does the separation of exponent factors come from? p is prime but p and k are not explicitly coprime?

Comment: It comes from `3^(kp) mod p = (3^p)^k mod p = (3^(p-1)*3)^k mod p = 3^k mod p`. And yes, `p` is prime but `k` can be any natural number.  The reason why this is necessary is that `3^(kp) mod kp = 11 mod kp` implies that `3^(kp) mod p = 11 mod p`.

Comment: @btilly "I can see how the program could run fast enough to be acceptable." Please elaborate. If ten million numbers are throw away each second, it takes more than 25 years to throw away all numbers between $10^{15}$ and $10^{16}$. If a number is not thrown away in the end, ...

Comment: @JohnL. What is your tight loop? Add `p`, decrement the count to the next multiple not filtered, set a bit.  In a fast language (Python isn't) that's maybe 10 cycles.  On  a 2 Ghz processor, that's 200 million per second. And this can probably be moved to a GPU for a lot more speed.  Plus you can parallelize.  I wouldn't be surprised if a cluster of 100 computers with a well optimized program can do thus in a week or two.

Comment: @btilly What about the numbers that are not thrown away? If only 1% remain, it may take much more time. By the way, please update your post instead of replying to my comment, as these estimates help answer the question.